# Token permanene en laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8

Amigos tengo desarrollado una aplicacion que sirve de backend esta hecho en Laravel 8, y utilice el metodo de autenticacion de laravel,

utilizo este metodo para la autenticacion

```
  $credentials = $request->only(['login', 'password']);
        if (!$token = auth()->guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->insertErrCustom(null, 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos.');
        }
        $user = User::where('login', $credentials['login'])->first();
        if ($user->isactive == 0) {
            $data = [
                'token' => null,
                'status' => $user->isactive,
            ];
            return $this->getOk($data, 'Cuenta desactivada');
        }

        $data = [
            'token' =>$token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 320,
            'user' => $user,
        ];
```

y me retorna un token el cual utilizo para llamar a los otros metodos del api. Pero este api caduca luego de unos minutos.
Ahora tengo que permitir a otra aplicacion conectarse a mi api, como le puedo dar un token que no caduque nunca, y asi puedan conectarse siempre desde la app externa.

Saludos

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens podes otorgar un token de larga expiracion ( revocable ) y refrescarlo en cada acceso o desautorizarlo totalmente ( ahi tal vez sea mas conveniente pasarse a un oauth )

Answer (score 0):

El uso de tokens que no expiran nunca no es recomendado por motivos de seguridad, ya que si por cualquier razón interceptan este token podrían usarlo indefinidamente.

La forma correcta de trabajar con las apps externas es que inicialmente hagan la llamada al método login este devuelva un token con una fecha de expiración y la app externa vaya usando este token hasta que expire. Una vez expirado, la app externa tiene que volver a realizar el login y obtener así un nuevo token válido.

Si aún así, por motivos técnicos necesitas ese token ilimitado, siempre que estés dispuesto a tener un posible agujero de seguridad, lo que puedes hacer es crearlo de forma manual, asignándolo al usuario en la base de datos y así poder validar su acceso de forma senzilla.